# Перевод из Unicode в Char

Tags: unicode, c++

```
#pragma _UNICODE
#pragma UNlCODE
#include <TChar.h>

char * c_f,*c_d;
wchar_t * h,*k;
...

WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, h, -1, c_d,0, NULL, NULL));
```

1. При компиляции ругается на функцию. (Е2379 Statement missing ). Подскажите в чем проблема?
2. При открытии файла `*.txt` кодировки `Unicode` в `Memo` он отображает только английские символы. Подскажите что не так?
3. Способны циклы работать с символами `wchar_t`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215963/how-do-you-properly-use-widechartomultibyte

Посмотри, может поможет

Answer (score 1):

В строке `#pragma UNlCODE` ошибка, надо - `#pragma UNICODE`.

В строке `WideCharToMultiByte(...))` ошибка, надо `WideCharToMultiByte(...)`

Попробуйте так

```
wchar_t* s = L"Здравствуй!";
char to[32] = { 0 };

::WideCharToMultiByte(1251, 0, s, -1, to, sizeof(to)/sizeof(to[0]), NULL, NULL);

e->Text = buf;
```

Да, итерация по w_char возможна, например

```
for (wchar_t c = 0x4ff0;  c < 0x5ff0;  c++) {
    std::wstring s(1, c);
}
```